# HTTP retrival using python3

Tags: python

```
import os
import urllib.request 


foldername="test_1"
os.makedirs(str(foldername))
tempurl=r"http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130802012237/camp-tv-series/images/thumb/e/e5/Adam.jpg/250px-Adam.jpg"

fullpath1=r"C:\Users\\files"+foldername
urllib.request.urlretrieve(tempurl, fullpath1)
```

This code is creating the folder but not retriving the file.
if I give obsolute path instead of fullpath it works. am I missing anything

Initially I gave a test url. now I am giving an example of a obsolute url

Comment: your url is incorrect

Comment: I gave a test url. not a real url

Comment: Do you mean "if I give an absolute path instead of a relative path it works"?

Comment: yes. if I give obsolut path in "" it works. If I give using a variable it does not work

Comment: why are you doing str(foldername) when it's already a string?

Comment: Did you add the path separator (e.g. "\\") before the foldername?

Comment: Also I suggest using https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join instead of a hard coded path separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing `urllib.request.urlretrieve(tempurl, fullpath1)` where `fullpath` does not specify the actual file being retrieved, change this to 
`urllib.request.urlretrieve(tempurl, os.path.join(fullpath1,"adam.jpg"))`

Furthermore, you're using relative path to create the directory then you use absolute path to reference it? Stick to one. In addition to this, you're converting a string to a string? Don't do that, it's already a string. Also, avoid using hardcoded paths. 
Full solution:

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as get

foldername="test_1"
os.makedirs(foldername, exist_ok=True)
url="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130802012237/camp-tv-series/images/thumb/e/e5/Adam.jpg/250px-Adam.jpg"
get(url, os.path.join(foldername,"adam.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code it's working, you need to use a correct name

```
import os
import urllib.request


foldername ="tesd"
os.makedirs(str(foldername)



tempurl =r"https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/1078702682/1078702682_6004950245001_6004956161001-vs.jpg"

archive_path, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(tempurl ,foldername+"/"+str(tempurl.split("/")[-1]), data=None)
```

Comment: the problem is in the name of the downloaded file so i removed the  full path and let juste the name of file